# How to apply a constraint to a power law model so that it passes through a specific data point (Python)

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, lmfit, power-law

I would like to develop a power law model using lmfit (or another library). Is there any way I can apply a constraint or bound to the model so that it has to pass through a specific data point (exp. the point (1, 2))

```
plm = models.PowerLawModel()

params = plm.guess(y_data, x=x_data)
result = plm.fit(y_data, params, x=x_data, )
const = round(result.best_values['amplitude'], 3)
exp = round(result.best_values['exponent'], 3)
best = result.best_fit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Power Law model, which is just `y = Amplitude * x**Exponent`, it would be pretty easy to write a constraint to force the model to always go through a point `(x0, y0)`.   You want `Amplitude` to be such that

```
 y0 = Amplitude*x0**Exponent
```

for any value of `Exponent`.  That is

```
 Amplitude = y0*x0**(-Exponent)
```

You can specify that in `lmfit` with something like

```
plm = models.PowerLawModel()
params = plm.guess(y_data, x=x_data)
params['amplitude'].expr = '{0:g}*{1:g}**(-exponent)'.format(y0, x0)
```

This will make `amplitude` not vary independently from `exponent` in the fit, and always take values that depend on the value of `exponent` and this expression.

Comment: Thank you for your help @M Newville!
I would like to develop a power law model so that it passes through two points ( point1: x0,y0, point2: x1,y1).
How may I add this constraint? When I apply 
params['amplitude'].expr = '{0:g}*{1:g}**(-exponent)'.format(y0, x0)
params['amplitude'].expr = '{0:g}*{1:g}**(-exponent)'.format(y1, x1)
it only fits the model to the second point.

Comment: um, that would make 0 free parameters.  That's regression.  Taking the log of your function would make it linear.